# How to filter rows by a variable bash

Tags: bash, awk

I need to filter row by a bash variable.

```
var=$(cat $1 | awk -F"\t" ' $1 == "foo1" { print $0 }')
echo $var
```

I'm trying this to replace the string "foo1" to a variable

```
column2=$(echo "foo1")
echo $column2
var=$(cat $1 | awk -v pres=$column2 -F"\t" ' $1 == $pres { print $0 }')
echo $var
```

In the parameter $1 i pass a file.txt that have the next text

```
foo2    AAAA    561214
foo3    AAAA    3
foo4    AAAA    10470670
foo5    AAAA    443507
foo1    AAAA    12473709
foo6    AAAA    1599707
foo8    AAAA    382820
foo7    BBBB    100000000000000
foo1    AAAA    12473709
foo1    AAAA    12473709
foo1    AAAA    12473709
foo1    AAAA    12473709
foo1    AAAA    12473709
foo1    AAAA    12473709
foo1    AAAA    12473709
```

I need to do this with a variable, because i need to loop for each distinct value of the first column.

EDIT

#

My question is different than [bash-How do i use shell variable in a awk script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) because i need to do a conditional to filter rows of a table in a file. I can do that is posted in that link, but i don't know how to combine to do

```
var=$(cat $1 | awk -F"\t" ' $1 == "foo1" { print $0 }')
```

that is working but when i tried to insert the variable stop working.

Comment: i've already seen it. I couldn't solve it with that.

Comment: Most likely you're asking less than what you should ask.  Why do you assign the filtered results to a variable and why do you need to do this in a loop.  The next steps most likely can be combined with the script and run only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this construction:

```
column2="foo1"
var=$(cat $1 | awk -v pres=$column2 -F"\t" ' $1 == pres { print $0 }')
```

Variables in `awk` do not need the `$` sign

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following.

```
column2="foo1"
var=$(awk -v pres="$column2" -F"\t" '$1==pres' "$1")
```

We need not to use `cat` here since `awk` could read Input_file itself.

2nd thing we need not to use `print` when we a condition is TRUE in code by default it will print that line(if no action given for that condition), so I removed it from code above.